# Why does my GUI freeze, brefore reading from Network stream, but works fine with - MessageBox.Sow(""); before reading it?

Tags: c#, aes, networkstream, diffie-hellman

I am a Computer Science student and this is my second project in c#, so I am not used to it yet and this is my second question on stackoverflow... 
I need to create a program with server and client, but their communication must be safe(I used Diffie-Hellman and AES).
My program freezes when I'm trying to read sent message through NetworkStream, program works fine, if I add show any message with MessageBox, before reading from stream. Also is there any way for client and server to generate the same AES.IV, besides my implementation of global IV?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Linq;

namespace Kodiranje
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    const int port = 22222;
    const string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    IPAddress ipServer = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    TcpListener server = null;
    TcpClient client = null;
    Thread thServer = null;
    NetworkStream dataStream = null;
    string receivedMessage = "";
    bool? izbira = null;
    Aes myAes = Aes.Create();

    byte[] iv = null;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        iv = myAes.IV;
        thServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startServer));
        thServer.IsBackground = true;
        thServer.Start();
        myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        iv = myAes.IV;
    }

    void startServer() {

        server = new TcpListener(ipServer, port);
        server.Start();
        textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText("Strežnik: zagnan na: IP: " + ip + ", port:" + port)));
        client = new TcpClient();
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream dataStream = client.GetStream();
        textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Sprejet nov uporabnik")));


        if (izbira == true)
        {
            byte[] serverPublicKey;
            ECDiffieHellmanCng serverDH = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
            serverDH.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
            serverDH.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
            serverPublicKey = serverDH.PublicKey.ToByteArray();



            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            while (!dataStream.DataAvailable) { }
            if (dataStream.DataAvailable)
                dataStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);


            byte[] serverCommoneKey = serverDH.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(message, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Dobil sem sporočilo: " + receivedMessage)));


            dataStream.Write(serverPublicKey, 0, serverPublicKey.Length);

            message = new byte[1024];

            myAes = Aes.Create();
            myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            myAes.Key = serverCommoneKey;
            myAes.IV = iv;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = myAes.CreateEncryptor(myAes.Key, iv);
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write("Serbus deda");

                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    int s = encrypted.Length;
                    MessageBox.Show(""); // freezes without message
                    dataStream.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);

                } 
            }
        }


        else {
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("serbus");
            dataStream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);


        }


    }

    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { // happens when client connects to the server
        if (izbira == null) {
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Izbrati morate ali boste datoteko prenesli ali poslali!")));
            return;
        }
        this.button1.Enabled = false;
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPAddress insertedIp = IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text);


        byte[] clientPublicKey;
        ECDiffieHellmanCng clientDH = new ECDiffieHellmanCng();
        clientDH.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
        clientDH.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        clientPublicKey = clientDH.PublicKey.ToByteArray();


        client.Connect(insertedIp, Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
        dataStream = client.GetStream();


        if (izbira == true)
        {

            dataStream.Write(clientPublicKey, 0, clientPublicKey.Length);

            byte[] message = new byte[1024];

            MessageBox.Show(""); // freezes without message
            while (true)
            {
                if (dataStream.DataAvailable)
                {

                    dataStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                    textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Client: Dobil sem sporočilo: " + receivedMessage)));
                    break;
                }
            }
            byte[] clientCommoneKey = clientDH.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(message, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));




            byte[] encryptedMessage = new byte[16];
            while (!dataStream.DataAvailable) { }
            MessageBox.Show(""); // freezes without message
            dataStream.Read(encryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.Length);
            myAes = Aes.Create();
            myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            myAes.Key = clientCommoneKey;
            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = myAes.CreateDecryptor(myAes.Key, iv);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(encryptedMessage))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        string plaintext;
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        MessageBox.Show("Sprejeto sporočilo " + plaintext);

                    }
                }
            }


        }
        else {

            byte[] message = new byte[1024];
            //MessageBox.Show("Serbus");
            while (!dataStream.DataAvailable)
            { }
            dataStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);

            receivedMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);
            textBox4.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Strežnik: Dobil sem sporočilo: " + receivedMessage)));
        }
    }

    void buttonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        izbira = true;
        this.buttonDownload.Enabled = false;
    }
    void buttonDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        izbira = false;
        this.buttonUpload.Enabled = false;
        this.button2.Text = "Prenesi";
    }



}
```

}

Comment: `MessageBox.Show("");` of course will block until a user interacts with it. Also `textBox4.Invoke` all of these are blocking calls as well; well temporarily.

Comment: The main thread of your program can do only one thing at a time.  Like any thread.  It can repaint the UI and respond to input *or* it can execute those while-loops.  It cannot do both.  MessageBox seems to fix the problem because it has a dispatcher loop, allowing repaints and user input to be processed again.  You'll need to use a separate worker thread.  And now those Invoke() calls actually start to make sense.  Do make sure you are not writing YAGNI code, these kind of assignments are usually meant to show proficiency in writing networking code, not UI code.